# Select a text box in Word and convert it to fraction

Tags: vba, ms-word

I try to convert a fraction `-10c⁷c⁵ / 5c⁷c⁵` or this `b⁴ / 6b⁴` in stacked fraction:

[image]

The following code only converts these fractions only and exclusively when there are only numbers:

```
Sub EscribeFraccionSel()
    With Selection.Range.Find
        .Text = "[0-9]@/[0-9]@"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        Do While .Execute
            .Parent.OMaths.Add(.Parent).OMaths(1).BuildUp
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

My question is, how can I modify the above code to convert fractions to stacked fraction?
I would greatly appreciate your help, thanks very much. Regards!

Comment: This is a question about whether or not you can define a set of rules that allow you to determine if a random selection of text in a word document can be converted to a fraction.  So please let us know what 'rules' (regexp with or without subsequent VBA code ) you have tried.  Based on the text examples you give above, finding the '/' and then extending the start and end of the range (separate actions) for the second found space might be a starter.

Comment: It is the only code I have had, I honestly do not know what to do, because I am just learning to handle vba

Comment: Google word moveendwhile/until and movestartwhile/until

Comment: Friend, my programming in vba is very very limited. And I try to organize 1000+ algebraic division exercises with polynomials in Word. If you have any way to help me modify the above code, I will be very grateful to you. Greetings!